# Sprite is not set and Animator glitching

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a Character Selection Menu for my mobile game. I have a GlobalManager Gamobject which is a singelton persisting through scenes. Then I have a GameSession Gameobject which controls stuff inside the Gameplay Scene.

In MenuScene inside character selection window when I click on the character toggle I call function, which sets sprite and runtimeAnimatorController into a field of GlobalManager. Then When I load the Gameplay inside Start I call the function below to set the Player sprite and Animator.

Problem is that the Animator is set but the sprite not. Also when I start moving the player it looks like the Animator is calling all Animations at once for 3-4 sec until it stabilizes and starts playing the right one.

```
#region Set Character
    public void SetCharacter(GameObject player)
    {
        if (CharacterSprite && CharacterRuntimeAnimatorController && player)
        {
            player.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = CharacterSprite;

            if (player.GetComponent<PlayerBehavior>() && player.GetComponent<Animator>())
            {
                player.GetComponent<Animator>().runtimeAnimatorController = CharacterRuntimeAnimatorController;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Expected behavior is that the sprite will be set and the Animator won't be glitching

EDIT:
When I deactivate Animator on Player GameObject the sprite is set. Still not sure what is causing this problem

EDIT 2:
Following script enables the sprite to be set but the Animation glitch remains

```
public void SetCharacter(GameObject player)
    {
        if (CharacterSprite && CharacterRuntimeAnimatorController && player)
        {
            player.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = CharacterSprite;

            if (player.GetComponent<PlayerBehavior>() && !player.GetComponent<Animator>())
            {
                player.AddComponent(typeof(Animator));
            }

            if (player.GetComponent<PlayerBehavior>() && player.GetComponent<Animator>())
            {
                player.GetComponent<Animator>().runtimeAnimatorController = CharacterRuntimeAnimatorController;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if the sprite is not set to CharacterSprite, it would suggest debugging is needed, and it would seem odd it would get to the part of the animation unless its just animating anyway

Comment: The behavior is really weird. I'm suspecting some sort of race condition happening

Comment: race conditions only truly happen in multithreaded stuff and unity hates true multi threaded.. so, unless you're multi co-routining stuff... you should be safe.. debugs should hold the key

Comment: Where is `SetCharacter` called? And it's hard to say without knowing your `AnimatorController` setup (states, transitions etc) `Also when I start moving the player it looks like the Animator is calling all Animations at once for 3-4 sec` where is the code for that?